# Vertical Flair?

Tags: feature-request, flair, information-display

The flair for StackOverflow are all horizontal, and they don't fit well in my blog.

Can we get some flair that is more vertically based?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There is a JSON option](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/54680.json). You could build a vertical-rep bar from that.

Comment: How about one that I can just install like all the other ones?

Comment: If that were an option, Nick, you wouldn't feel all supra-1337 :)